# Place in code to initialize Sentry in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, sentry

I use Symfony 4.2. I follow official Sentry instructions here

https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/quickstart/?platform=php

Composer command finishes successfully

```
composer require sentry/sdk:2.0.0
```

But where in Simfony files should I place the next line of code (with my credentials, of course)?

```
Sentry\init(['dsn' => 'https://<key>@sentry.io/<project>' ]);
```

Comment: I think you should check out [Sentry Symfony SDK](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-symfony/releases/tag/3.0.0-beta1) instead of trying to implement it yourself (the linked 3.0 beta 1 is the release that works with the 2.0 version of the SDK).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sentry\init(['dsn' => 'https://<key>@sentry.io/<project>' ]);
```

should go into the boostrap file, basically the file that initializes your project. (The file where you register error handlers, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, I realize about generic boostrap file. And I tried paste that code into Symfony's config/bootstrap.php. but it doesn't work.

Comment: @mutan Can you provide more context into this issue?

Comment: Acctually, nothing to add. I have fresh installation of Symfony 4 (`composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project`). And want to add Sentry to project. That's all.

Comment: One possible issue could be, Symphony's default error/exception handler is invoked. In this case you need to override it with Sentry's exception handler. Refer https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#custom-exception-controller

Comment: You can register Sentry's exception handler like this
`use Sentry\ErrorHandler;

ErrorHandler::registerOnce(function (\Throwable $exception): void {
    // ...
});
`

Answer (score 0):

To use Sentry with Symfony, you should use the [official bundle](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-symfony) for it. After the installation, you need to edit its configuration file *(config/packages/sentry.yaml)* as follow:

```
sentry:
    dsn: '<YOU_DSN_HERE>'
```

Comment: In general this is the best approach, but there are legit cases when you might want to do manual integration. E.g. right now (Jan 2021) sentry PHP SDK is v3.x, but bundle only supports ^2.0 - because of that you cannot use any of the performance tracing capabilities of Sentry (and you cannot have 2 separate SDK versions running alongside without some black magic). Bundle is also still pending PHP 8.0 support, while SDK already has it for some time.

Comment: @mkilmanas I want to use performance tracing, where can i add the init please ?

Comment: @pcmanprogrammeur - Make sure you use sentry-bundle v4.x; Then in config/packages/sentry.yaml add sentry.options.traces_sample_rate: X where 0.0 < X <= 1.0. This will control what percentage of all requests should be traced (performance measured). Any value > 0.0 enables the feature. 1.0 means trace ALL requests (which comes at a cost of performance penalty). Consider proxying your sentry connectivity via Relay https://docs.sentry.io/product/relay/ for better responsiveness (otherwise sending data to sentry will consume your request execution time)

Comment: @mkilmanas, Thank you for your help. I use "sentry/sentry-symfony": "^4.0" and add sentry:options:traces_sample_rate: 1.0 but nothing append :( Do i have to init Sentry like that : https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/performance/ please ? However, i had a throw new \Exception("Example exception."); i have the issue in Sentry but nothing about performance.

Comment: @pcmanprogrammeur - without seeing more details about your setup I can't really say what it could be. So I suggest you post a separate question with full config details and maybe someone will be able to spot something. It's also a great shame that Sentry-Symfony documentation is a mixture of 3.2 docs, some hints to 4.0 functionality and them mostly misleading/unnecessary copy-paste of pure php docs

Comment: @pcmanprogrammeur According to this https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/blob/master/src/Options.php#L137-L145 that one parameter should be all you really need. Make sure it is placed under 'options' key and that it is not misspelled: 'traces_sample_rate'